# Removing nan from list - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove 'nan' from a list, but it is refusing to go. I have tried both np.nan and 'nan'.

This is my code:

```
ztt = []
for i in z:
    if i != 'nan':
        ztt.append(i) 
ztt
```

or:

```
ztt = []
for i in z:
    if i != np.nan:
        ztt.append(i) 
ztt
```

I am still getting the output:

```
[[46.0, 34.0, 32.0, 40.0, 34.0, 29.0, 38.0, 39.0, 45.0, 32.0, 28.0, 43.0],
 [32.0, 30.0, 67.0, 66.0, 28.0, 19.0, 39.0, 32.0, 51.0, 28.0, 20.0, 36.0],
 [29.0, 24.0, 37.0, 31.0, 32.0, 34.0, 28.0, 31.0, 28.0, 33.0, 28.0, 39.0],
 [27.0, 29.0, 35.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]]
```

Anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: Getting a 'ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'?

Comment: note `np.nan == np.nan`  is `False`! You could use `is` or one of `numpy`'s own checks

Comment: Sorry Chris, what do you mean by using 'is'? thank you

Comment: `is` is an operator, anyway, you should be doing `if not np.isnan(i)`; also you have nested lists, so you need to iterate through them

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you. I will try now

Comment: Tried that, getting this error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()......   it mentions arrays, is that just a standard error? I am working with lists

Comment: You have nested lists, look at your data structure!

Comment: I have managed to get it working with arrays, rather than a list. I am not sure if that gets around a potential nested list issue. Thank you so much for your help Chris!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ztt = []
for z_i in z:
    row = []
    for z_ij in z_i:
        if math.isnan(z_ij):
            row.append(z_ij)
        # If you want to replace with, for example, 0:
        # else:
        #     row.append(0)
    ztt.append(row)
```

Alternatively, with nested list comprehensions:

```
ztt = [[z_ij for z_ij in zi if math.isnan(z_ij)] for z_i in z]
```

Btw, if you are using NumPy, you probably can just do:

```
import numpy as np

ztt =[value[~np.isnan(value)] for value in z]
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answers. I tried, but it is still showing nans? :S

Comment: they are not strings, look at the output

Comment: `[[z_ij for z_ij in zi if not np.isnan(z_ij)] for z_i in z]`

Comment: Hey, thank you! changed zi to z, but I am getting 'ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()' error coming up.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Right, I see, I guess the "float is required" messages came from the object being an array instead of a pure Python float...

Comment: @ScoutEU Updated

Answer (score 5):

```
for i in z:
    if not math.isnan(i):
        ztt.append(i)
```

Comment: Getting a SyntaxError: invalid syntax error? I have imported the 'Math' module?

Comment: @ScoutEU import math?

Comment: It should be `if not math.isnan(i):`. Also, as a list comprehension: `[i for i in z if not math.isnan(i)]`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'import math', getting a 'float is required' for your solution jdehesa?

Comment: z is from this code:       z = lineFDFTran.values.tolist()  ..... I cant send the data as it is sensitive work data :/

Answer (score 3):

nan in your case DOESN'T require quotes, coz nan is a special number. When it is quoted it becomes a string type. So It should look like this:

```
ztt = []
for i in z:
    if !math.isnan(i)
        ztt.append(i) 
ztt
```

or

```
ztt =[value for value in z if not math.isnan(value)]
```

Comment: Hey, getting a 'NameError: name 'nan' is not defined' error' when I dont put quote marks around?

Comment: @ScoutEU that's because you need np.nan; anyway this answer fails because it misses the fundamental point that np.nan == np.nan is False

Comment: Thank you Jack. It i says 'a float is required'... any idea?

Comment: What option did you use?

Comment: I tried both. I ended up converting it to an array which fixed the issue. Just need to get that array back to a list now :)... thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your code is, that `np.nan != np.nan`is `True`

You might also consider using arrays instead of lists.

```
import numpy as np
z = np.array(z)   #convert into array, which allows other indexing
ztt = z[np.logical_not(np.isnan(z))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use while in a for loop i.e

```
k = [[46.0, 34.0, 32.0, 40.0, 34.0, 29.0, 38.0, 39.0, 45.0, 32.0, 28.0, 43.0],
 [32.0, 30.0, 67.0, 66.0, 28.0, 19.0, 39.0, 32.0, 51.0, 28.0, 20.0, 36.0],
 [29.0, 24.0, 37.0, 31.0, 32.0, 34.0, 28.0, 31.0, 28.0, 33.0, 28.0, 39.0],
 [27.0, 29.0, 35.0, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan']]

for i,j in enumerate(k):
    while 'nan' in k[i]: k[i].remove('nan')
```

Output :

```
[[46.0, 34.0, 32.0, 40.0, 34.0, 29.0, 38.0, 39.0, 45.0, 32.0, 28.0, 43.0],
 [32.0, 30.0, 67.0, 66.0, 28.0, 19.0, 39.0, 32.0, 51.0, 28.0, 20.0, 36.0],
 [29.0, 24.0, 37.0, 31.0, 32.0, 34.0, 28.0, 31.0, 28.0, 33.0, 28.0, 39.0],
 [27.0, 29.0, 35.0]]
```

```
m = [[46.0, 34.0, 32.0, 40.0, 34.0, 29.0, 38.0, 39.0, 45.0, 32.0, 28.0, 43.0],
  [32.0, 30.0, 67.0, 66.0, 28.0, 19.0, 39.0, 32.0, 51.0, 28.0, 20.0, 36.0],
  [29.0, 24.0, 37.0, 31.0, 32.0, 34.0, 28.0, 31.0, 28.0, 33.0, 28.0, 39.0],
  [27.0, 29.0, 35.0,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]]

for i,j in enumerate(m):
    while np.nan in m[i]: m[i].remove(np.nan)
```

Output:

```
[[46.0, 34.0, 32.0, 40.0, 34.0, 29.0, 38.0, 39.0, 45.0, 32.0, 28.0, 43.0],
 [32.0, 30.0, 67.0, 66.0, 28.0, 19.0, 39.0, 32.0, 51.0, 28.0, 20.0, 36.0],
 [29.0, 24.0, 37.0, 31.0, 32.0, 34.0, 28.0, 31.0, 28.0, 33.0, 28.0, 39.0],
 [27.0, 29.0, 35.0]]
```

Update since this was written quite a while ago:

```
k = [list(filter(lambda x : x !='nan',i)) for i in k]
```

Comment: Ye, I think this was a problem with nested lists (I still get nans on your very helpful answer)... thank you :)