# Mapping and Updating dataframe contents to a partial dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

### Problem

`TypeA` and `TypeB` columns of the following dataframe *df*:

```
   Mix             TypeA  TypeB
0  701        12,101,102    9.0
1  702           7,11,16    7.0
2  703  12,102,NaN,11,16    7.0
3  704            5,3,16    NaN
4  705   101,102,10,3,16    6.0
```

...needs to be mapped to the dictionary:

```
code_dict = {12: 'a', 102: 'b', 7: 'c', 11: 'd', 16: 'e', 5: 'f'}
```

### Desired Result

```
   Mix             TypeA  TypeB
0  701           a,101,b    9
1  702             c,d,e    c
2  703       a,b,NaN,d,e    c
3  704             f,3,e    NaN
4  705      101,b,10,3,e    6
```

### Efforts made

#### Attempt # 1

Thought *df* could be split, expanded and mapped `code_dict` to df using a simple command like:

```
pd.concat([df.TypeA.str.split(',', expand=True), df.TypeB]).apply(lambda x: code_dict[x], 1)
```

...but it gives the `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

#### Attempt # 2

Made a function *f*:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        result = code_dict[x]
    except KeyError:
        result = x
    return result
```

...and used it as ...

```
dfa = df.TypeA.str.split(',', expand=True).\
        apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').applymap(f)

pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :2], dfa, df.TypeB.map(f)], axis=1)
```

...which is close to the desired result, though not exactly that.

### Queries

1. Is there a vectorized way to replace / update the expanded df without using `map` and `applymap` on function *f* ?
2. To get to the desired result, I tried manipulate *dfa* using
   `recs = [list(i.values()) for i in dfa.to_dict('records')]`. This gives a list of lists as follows:

```
[['a', 101, 'b', nan, nan], 
['c', 'd', 'e', nan, nan], 
['a', 'b', nan, 'd', 'e'], 
['f', 3, 'e', nan, nan], 
[101, 'b', 10.0, 3.0, 'e']]
```

... and I am not able to clear the `nan` in it.

Is there a way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest use `dict.get(key, key)` method here - it working similar like `d[key]` but if no match original value is returned (second argument).

In column `TypeA` are strings, so for match are converted keys of dictionary to `string`s with `split` and `join` back, for column `TypeB` is used original dictionary, because numeric (if strings too, use `d`):

```
code_dict = {12: 'a', 102: 'b', 7: 'c', 11: 'd', 16: 'e', 5: 'f'}
d = {str(k): v for k, v in code_dict.items()}

df.TypeA = df.TypeA.apply(lambda x: ','.join(d.get(y, y) for y in x.split(',')))
df.TypeB = df.TypeB.apply(lambda x: code_dict.get(x, x))
print (df)
   Mix         TypeA TypeB
0  701       a,101,b     9
1  702         c,d,e     c
2  703   a,b,NaN,d,e     c
3  704         f,3,e   NaN
4  705  101,b,10,3,e     6
```

---

> Is there a vectorized way to replace / update the expanded df without using map and applymap on function f ?

In my opinion not, because here is `replace` problematic, because need processing values between `,`.

> To get to the desired result, I tried manipulate dfa using recs = [list(i.values()) for i in dfa.to_dict('records')].

There is multiple solution, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45375381), e.g.:

```
recs =[value[~np.isnan(value)] for value in recs]
```